# While adding foreign key relation mysql (5.5.29) gives ERROR 1050:

Tags: php, mysql

While adding foreign key relation MySQL gives `ERROR 1050`:

I have 2 tables and trying to give foreign key relation with other, but it gives below error.

> ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'yellowbikes.#sql-1e8_82' (errno: 121)

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `yellowbikes`.`schedule` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `bike_number`
  FOREIGN KEY (`bike_number` )
  REFERENCES `yellowbikes`.`bike` (`bike_number` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
, ADD INDEX `bike_number_idx` (`bike_number` ASC)
```

> ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.
>
> **ERROR 1050:** Table 'schedule' already exists

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
   `bikeid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `bike_number` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`bikeid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Have you try the SQL statement without 'yellowbikes' ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you dont have a table with the name schedule? Try DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schedule before your second statement.

Comment: Sounds like a broken table if it does exist.

Comment: Hi Alex,no there is no separate table as 'schedule', also already tried with some different name, stil the same issue

Comment: Are you running the MySQL server on Windows?

Comment: Hi Yak, Yes am runnning it on win XP, it worked fine for my 4 tables which i already created but now trying to create 1 more table and give foreign key relation and it doesnt works!!

Comment: HI  Claudio, I tried but stil same issue!!

Comment: Hi team, Just happned to found out that this is the 3rd time I am using as foreign key for other tables from this table.. Also one more observation that if I remove one foreign key relation with other and try this foreign key relation its working!! but if i try to apply that particular ralation back again,, it gives same error,, it means that max 2 TIMES A FOREIGN KEY CAN BE APPLIED FOR ANY GIVEN PRIMARY KEY??

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure they are both the same type.`Schedule` is having type `utf8`. Check whthr `yellowbikes` is of type `default` ?!?! If so, change it to `utf8`

**Edit:**

Also you can check if you MySql DB is MyISAM. If so, chane it to InnoDB because if you need the database to enforce foreign key constraints, or you need the database to handle the changes made by set of DML operations as single unit of work then you would choose InnoDB over MyISAM, since these features are absent from the MyISAM engine.

Comment: Hi Vin, Yes both are of same tyoe , i already have some more table and relations created, but now when am creating new one now, it throws this error

Comment: If your MySQL DB Engine is MyISAM, you won't be able to add foreign key after table is created. if so, you can change it to InnoDB..(ans edited)

Comment: Hi Vinayak, Engine is INNODB itself for both the tables, with collation UTF8-default collation

Comment: Check this post '[16 Feb 2011 12:41] Desmond Coertzen' in this link
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30513#c174255

Comment: Hi Vinayak, Its ok but i dont think it is behaving the same way :( btw thanks for searching it..

Comment: Hi team, Just happned to found out that this is the 3rd time I am using as foreign key for other tables from this table.. Also one more observation that if I remove one foreign key relation with other and try this foreign key relation its working!! but if i try to apply that particular ralation back again,, it gives same error,, it means that max 2 TIMES A FOREIGN KEY CAN BE APPLIED FOR ANY GIVEN PRIMARY KEY??